# WELD-001409 , jbpm 6.1

Tags: jbpm, weblogic12c, weld

I want to deploy a .war on weblogic 12c. I use jbpm 6.1 in my project. This app is very very simple, so I am sure there is no error in my code, so the error I receive must be from libs I imported to my project, some config, or maybe incompatibility in app server and frameworks I use. 
When I want to deploy it on the weblogic, I receive this error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 3
exceptions: Exception 0 : org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: 
WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [ExecutorService] with qualifiers 
[@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private 
org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceLifeCycleController.executorService]. 
Possible dependencies [[Producer Method [ExecutorService] with qualifiers
[@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public 
org.jbpm.executor.impl.mem.InMemoryExecutorServiceProducer.produceExecutorService()], Producer Method [ExecutorService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public org.jbpm.executor.impl.jpa.JPAExecutorServiceProducer.produceExecutorService()]]] at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:318) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:147) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:386) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:371) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379) at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:110) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:76) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:49) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Exception 0 : org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [ExecutorQueryService] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private org.jbpm.executor.impl.AvailableJobsExecutor.queryService]. Possible dependencies [[Producer Method [ExecutorQueryService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public org.jbpm.executor.impl.jpa.JPAExecutorServiceProducer.produceQueryService()], Producer Method [ExecutorQueryService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public org.jbpm.executor.impl.mem.InMemoryExecutorServiceProducer.produceQueryService()]]] at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:318) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:147) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:386) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:371) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379) at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:110) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:76) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:49) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Exception 0 : org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @PersistenceUnit @Inject private org.jbpm.executor.impl.jpa.JPAExecutorServiceProducer.emf] at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:315) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:147) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:386) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:371) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379) at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:110) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:76) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:49) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) :org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:Exception List with 3 exceptions: Exception 0 : org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [ExecutorService] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private org.jbpm.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceLifeCycleController.executorService]. Possible dependencies [[Producer Method [ExecutorService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public org.jbpm.executor.impl.mem.InMemoryExecutorServiceProducer.produceExecutorService()], Producer Method [ExecutorService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public org.jbpm.executor.impl.jpa.JPAExecutorServiceProducer.produceExecutorService()]]] at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:318) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:147) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:386) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:371) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379) at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:110) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:76) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:49) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Exception 0 : org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [ExecutorQueryService] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private org.jbpm.executor.impl.AvailableJobsExecutor.queryService]. Possible dependencies [[Producer Method [ExecutorQueryService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public org.jbpm.executor.impl.jpa.JPAExecutorServiceProducer.produceQueryService()], Producer Method [ExecutorQueryService] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces public org.jbpm.executor.impl.mem.InMemoryExecutorServiceProducer.produceQueryService()]]] at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:318) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:147) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:386) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:371) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379) at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:110) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:76) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:49) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Exception 0 : org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EntityManagerFactory] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @PersistenceUnit @Inject private org.jbpm.executor.impl.jpa.JPAExecutorServiceProducer.emf] at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:315) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:147) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:386) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:371) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379) at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:110) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:76) at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:49) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

I don't know if it matters : I didn't add any beans.xml to my project.
Non of classes mentioned in this error log is my own classes, all are from jar files of jbpm. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Are you able to run your program in any other container(or standalone)? I want to know whether this problem is specific to weblogic or not?

Comment: I haven't try it out yet. I will do, and tell you the result.